# Is there a way to setup your own source tools on eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse

I'm not sure source tools is the right way to define what I mean so I'll give you an example.

In my code I may have something like that

```
<div>
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Since I want my app to be translated I use the _ function.

So I would like to be able to select "Hello" and to click somewhere on the context menu to a launch a tools of mine that would change "Hello" to `<?=_("Hello");?>`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).
Eclipse has some awesome search and replace functionality.
Do a project wide file search on *.html files with the regexp `>([^<]+)<` and then replace with `><?=_("$1");?>`
Afterwards you can mark which replacements should actually take place.

It might not get you all the way, but it sure is going to help with the bulk of it.